# redireccionar con javascript segun campo de formulario

Tags: javascript, web, redirección

Tengo un formulario que recibe una cadena y la envía a un servlet java. Estoy tratando de agregar un codigo javascript que permita que, si el usuario introduce "000", lo redirecciones a la pagina de login.
Esto lo hago colocando un eventlistener onsubmit en el formulario, pero la función nunca es ejecutada.
Aca mi pagina:

Tengo esto dentro del header de mi pagina:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function enviar(){
                valor = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
                if(valor==="000"){
                    location.href="login.jsp";
                }else{
                    return true;
                }

            }

        </script>
```

Y este es el formulario:

```
<FORM id="codSeguimiento" onsubmit="enviar();" action="consultaServlet" method="POST">
                <p>Seguimiento de tramites</p>
                <input id="codigo" name="codigo" type=text maxlength="10"><br>
                <input id="boton" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Consultar">        
</FORM>
```

He probado comentando el codigo de la función, y colocando simplemente un alert("texto"); Y esto nunca se ejecuta. Por lo que deduzco la función nunca es ejecutada.

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? No tengo mucha idea del tema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La funcion JS `enviar` no se ejecuta ya que dentro del formulario existe un `input` con nombre `enviar`. Simplemente debes cambiar el nombre de la función, ejemplo:

```
function enviarTramite(evt) {
    valor = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    if (valor === "000") {
        location.href = "login.jsp";
        evt.preventDefault(); // Evitamos el submit en nuevos navegadores
        return false; // Evitamos el submit viejos navegadores
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

<form id="codSeguimiento" onsubmit="enviarTramite(event);" action="consultaServlet" method="POST">
    <p>Seguimiento de tramites</p>
    <input id="codigo" name="codigo" type=text maxlength="10">
    <br>
    <input id="boton" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Consultar">
</form>
```

**Nota**: `enviarTramite` tiene 2 de lineas extras para evitar que el formulario se envíe al mismo tiempo que se realiza la re-dirección.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/wh4ojhzs/

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si funcionó :)